# I am trying to reverse an array using javascript recursion but its not working. Need help what I am missing here

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reverse an array using javascript recursion but its not working. Need help what I am missing here.

```js
function reverseArrayHelper(left, right, arr) {
  if (left >= right) return; // base condition: if l an r collide then only return

  // do the small task: swapping left with right
  let temp = arr[left];
  arr[left] = arr[right];
  arr[right] = temp;
  // arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]

  return reverseArrayHelper(left + 1, right - 1, arr); // ask recursion to do the remaining task
}

function reverseArray(arr, m) {
  return reverseArrayHelper(m + 1, arr.length - 1, arr);
}

console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

Comment: What does this parameter `m` in `reverseArray(arr, m)` used for?

Comment: What is meant by "_it's not working_"?

Comment: By reverse you mean you are expecting [6,5,4,3,2,1]? If yes, why do you start at m(middle i suppose)? Try starting at 0

Comment: Aside: you can avoid use of a `temp` variable and [swap variables using a destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#swapping_variables) in a single statement: `[arr[l], arr[r]] = [arr[r], arr[l]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about the response is undefined, you have to return the array here `if (left >= right) return arr;`. Since you were not returning a value in this line, the response was undefined.

But the logic for the reverse is up to you.

```js
function reverseArrayHelper(left, right, arr) {
    if (left >= right) return arr; // base condition: if l an r collide then only return

    // do the small task: swapping left with right
    let temp = arr[left];
    arr[left] = arr[right];
    arr[right] = temp;
    // arr[left], arr[right] = arr[right], arr[left]

    return reverseArrayHelper(left + 1, right - 1, arr); // ask recursion to do the remaining task
}

function reverseArray(arr, m) {
    return reverseArrayHelper(m + 1, arr.length - 1, arr);
}

console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that you are **not returning the modified array** from the `reverseArray` function.

```js
function reverseArrayHelper(left, right, arr) {
  if (left >= right) return arr;

  let temp = arr[left];
  arr[left] = arr[right];
  arr[right] = temp;

  return reverseArrayHelper(left + 1, right - 1, arr);
}

function reverseArray(arr, m) {
  return reverseArrayHelper(m + 1, arr.length - 1, arr);
}
// This code reverses all elements after the 4th element (after index 3)
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3));
```

In the `reverseArrayHelper` function, I added `arr` as the base case return value. This ensures that the modified array is returned all the way up the recursive calls.

With this code, to reverse the entire array you should:

```js
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to find the mid point. I've fixed your code below. You should return the array in base condition.

```
function reverseArray(arr, left = 0, right = arr.length - 1) {
  if (left >= right) {
    return arr;
  }

  const temp = arr[left];
  arr[left] = arr[right];
  arr[right] = temp;

  return reverseArray(arr, left + 1, right - 1);
}
```